# How does the fetch api work with express when trying to send a json object

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api

I have a system in place where I have a nodejs app:

```js
app.post('/action', (req, res) => {
 ...
const option = req.body.option
 ...
switch (option) {
    case 'getinfo':
        objectToSend = {"foo": "bar"}
        // i tried using
        res.json(objectToSend)
        // and
        res.send(JSON.stringify(objectToSend))
        // but neither got me anywhere
    break
}
```

And a website that sends a post request using fetch like this (infoModal is the function I use to display data) (I got the action function sent on discord and have been using it since then, but ive never had to do anything with the response)

```js
let action = async (i) => {
    res = await fetch("/action", {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(i)
    })
    return await res.json
}
action({
            option: 'getinfo'
        }).then(j => {
            infoModal(j.foo,'ok')
        })
```

I can't really fix either the backend or frontend since both have to work for me to confirm it works...

**EDIT:**
These are my requires, uses and sets:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
 ...
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
let ejs = require('ejs')
const fs = require('fs')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var colors = require('colors')

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'frontend'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Comment: I think the client method should say `return await res.json();`

Comment: You can use postman to check the api with running only back-end. [here](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

Comment: You need a bodyparser that understands JSON

Comment: @slebetman already have

Comment: [You need to do some debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Are there any errors? Look at the Network tab. Is the request being sent? With the right headers and body? Does it get a response? Add some logging to the server. Does the route get called? Does `req.body` have any value?  Does it enter the right branch of the switch? Just telling us [it doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) doesn't help us help you. Tell us what you expect to happen and how that differs from what happens.

Comment: Does look like the problem is just a typo and you got to call the response json method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious mistake is not executing the `jeson()` method of the Fetch response. And, although harmless, the second `await` statement is not really necessary - the async functions anyway wrap what is returned in a promise.

```
return res.json();
```

If that doesn't work -

1. See what your developer console says. It should give you lot of information about the request. If there is an error, follow the info (response code, any error message etc) and try to determine the problem.
2. Use a rest client such as POSTMAN to verify your backend first. When you know that it can respond well to a proper request, you can try your front-end with confidence and get more understanding on how the response should be handled.